# how to balance minibatches on keras when training a convolutional neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, mini-batch

I am training a convolutional neural network on images (with size 299, 299, 3). The images can have labels: 0, 1 or 2 (multiclass classification), and the 3 classes are very unbalanced. To improve the training phase I want to make sure that each minibatch contains all three classes. How can I do this?

I am using flow_from_dataframe to pass the images to the neural network.

```
train_generator=datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
dataframe=train, 
directory=None, 
x_col="directory",
y_col="label",
batch_size=64, 
seed=42, 
shuffle=False, 
class_mode='categorical',
target_size=(299,299))
```

Comment: 1) balancing dataset is easier than balancing every batch 2) balancing classes in the training set is not always a good idea, more context is needed to see if it's justified

Comment: As suggested in the above comment, balancing the dataset beforehand is easier. You might want to look at data augmentation techniques.

Comment: @Marat  Sorry, I forgot to say that I have very small dataset, so I wanted to avoid undersampling because every piece of data is precious. I have only about 700 imgs for training (350 class 1 - 219 class 0 - 111 class 2).  Tips?

Comment: 1) balancing the dataset as a whole will have the same effect as balancing every batch, but is a lot easier 2) what is the class distribution in test set or general population?

Comment: @Marat The training set is the one I mentioned in the previous comment, and I created the test set. I created the test set balanced, to have the metrics balanced as well: 40 images per class, for a total of 120 imgs. In conclusion I have 680 images for training and 120 for testing.

Comment: Test set is used to estimate performance of your model in real life. If classes are balanced in the test set but not IRL this metric doesn't make any sense. There are definitely more misconceptions here, which cannot be covered in a comment discussion. Perhaps, you need to take an ML class

Comment: @Marat I am doing purely academic work, I am building a model to predict which class the image belongs to. 
The test is solely to test the final performance of my model on unseen data. 
If it were an unbalanced test set I would have to balance the metrics (macro - micro...). So why can't I balance the test set beforehand since I have the possibility to do so?